# C Substrings Methods

Tags: c, linux, string

Hello I am trying to extract a small string from a larger string, basically I am given a string with delimiters and I need to rearrange it. so lets say I have "@the president#" @ shows the place I have to start and # is the end of the substring. I am using strchr to get a pointer to the @ symbol and I know that I need to search until I find the # symbol. There isnt a from x to y function though and I'm not sure how to go from a char pointer a to a symbol #.

```
    char *garbage = "@the president#";
    int count = 0;
    char a = strchr(garbage, @);
    char *sentence = NULL;
    while(start at a, garbage[count] != #){
       char sentence[count] = garbage[count];
       count++;
    }
```

Comment: @abelenky You are right, I posted the rest of the code and where the variables come from, I hope that it is clear the part which I do not understand how to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
const char* posAtSign = strchr(searchString,'@');
if (posAtSign != NULL) {
    const char* posPoundSign = strchr(posAtSign+1,'#');
    if (posPoundSign != NULL) {
        const int numChars = posPoundSign - posAtSign - 1;
        strncpy(substringBuffer,posAtSign+1,numChars);
    }
}
```

Tested code:

```
char searchString[] = "@the president#";
char substringBuffer[128];

const char* posAtSign = strchr(searchString,'@');
if (posAtSign != NULL) {
    const char* posPoundSign = strchr(posAtSign+1,'#');
    if (posPoundSign != NULL) {
        const int numChars = posPoundSign - posAtSign - 1;
        strncpy(substringBuffer,posAtSign+1,numChars);
        substringBuffer[numChars] = '\0';
        printf("substring: '%s'", substringBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will work but I get a segmentation fault at the strncpy() line. It is not giving me any other information besides segmentation fault. Any ideas why?

Comment: 2 things to check: (1) probably good to test whether numChars > 0 before the strncpy, and (2) is substringBuffer allocated with enough space to hold numChars+1?

Comment: When I print out numChars it is always > 0 and substringBuffer is declared as char *substringBuffer (should have plenty of space). Could it be the linux servers that are screwing it up?

Comment: Something else to check: substringBuffer must be declared to be of type 'char*', but it also must have some memory allocated for its use. Do you have some memory allocated for it? See my example above to see how to statically allocate the size. Use malloc (and don't forget the subsequent 'free') if you don't know how big it might be in advance.

Comment: declaring it that way works for me as well, I though that declaring it as a pointer gave it space and that you didnt have to explicitly declare it like you have.

Comment: Just because it's declared to be a 'char*' type doesn't actually give it any space to hold anything (other than the memory address). You can allocate it statically like I did with "char substringBuffer[128]" or you could do it dynamically with: char* substringBuffer; substringBuffer = (char*) malloc(4096);